# Adding a "new" view onto an app without views

Tags: ios, iphone

I started an "empty app" from the xcode wizard.
it has no view controllers, only the app delegate.

how do I add a default "empty" view?
I can add the class, but how do you tie it into the app?

and yes, I know I can go back and have the wizard generate another app, but I'd like to do that myself programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
self.window = [ [ UIWindow alloc ] initWithFrame:[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ] ];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
self.window.rootViewController = [YourViewControllerClass new];
```

to

```
- ( BOOL ) application:( UIApplication* ) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:( NSDictionary* ) launchOptions
```

Comment: This line `self.window.rootViewController = [YourViewControllerClass new];` adds view controller.

Comment: oh right sorry didnt see that - upvoted even before. ;) -- I'd avoid using new though